# Face error in apache-tomcat-7.0.25

Tags: tomcat, jboss

I have project running fine in tomcat 5 and jdk1.6.0 but in tomcat 7 it gives following error 
Error:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]
andardHost[nsncatbranch].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[nsncatbranch].St
ardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name invoker
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3204)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3183)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1302)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1302)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
Feb 2, 2012 3:25:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]
andardHost[nsncatbranch]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:293)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:646)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[nsncatbranch]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1138)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is this line

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name invoker
```

Meaning that you seem to have specified some servlet mapping that relies on a setting that is present in older Tomcats but not in your TC7 instance. Inspect the server config and here especially the settings for `StandardHost[nsncatbranch]` for invalid values.